# Using translate and rotate in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a div rotate and move along the Y axis. I got it to work individually but not in the same time. This is the code i use to rotate the div:

```
function rotate_horizon_bg(deg){
  var rotate = "rotate(" + (deg) + "deg);";
  var tr = new Array(
    "transform:" + rotate, 
    "-moz-transform:" + rotate,
    "-webkit-transform:" + rotate,
    "-ms-transform:" + rotate,
    "-o-transform:" + rotate
  );


  var horizon_bg = document.getElementById("horizon_bg");
  horizon_bg.setAttribute("style", tr.join(";"));
}
```

This works perfectly to rotate the div. If I make a new function to transelateY. Only transelateY will work.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work 
simultaneous?

Comment: Your output will look like `transform: translateY(100px) rotate(45deg);`. Figure out how you get there.

Comment: Controlling it directly might be a little bit annoying over time. It's recommended to use a library that handles that, including browser compatibility for you.

Comment: You need to make sure your transform rules don't overwrite each other. You can list several transform commands separated by space. And btw, the word is ***translate***, not *transelate*.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the effects. Here's a literal example:

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-120px,-30px)
```

```js
function rotate_horizon_bg(rotateDeg, x, y){
  var horizon_bg = document.getElementById("horizon_bg");
  horizon_bg.style.transform  = "rotate(" + rotateDeg + "deg) translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
}

rotate_horizon_bg(-30, 3, 3);
```

```html
<div id="horizon_bg">Translate Me!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try this. My operation has two variables that is defined in my code,   rotate_horizon_bg(state.roll) and translateY_horizon_bg(state.pitch)

Comment: @JAR4x4 That's fine. `translate` can take a single argument (x axis) or two arguments (x axis, y axis) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate I set this example up to use x and y. If you only want to use a y axis, you'll need to specify the arguments with 0 for the x axis, as in `translate(0, yourYvariable)`